# Настроить 404 ошибку

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Настроить 404 ошибку, чтобы страницы типа `http://mysite/адрес-от-балды` не создавали дубли, сейчас по умолчанию все время отображает главную страницу,а нужно что бы выдавало ошибку 404...

Как это можно настроить, что бы такие адреса перенаправлялись на ошибку? сервер на nginx, CMS - WP

Comment: Настроить в чём?

Comment: Это всё зависит от конкретного веб-сервера и, раз сейчас выводится главная, от его текущих настроек

Comment: сайт написан на WP

Comment: @dmitro_bolva пока что это ни о чём не говорит. Это всё зависит в первую от конкретного веб-сервера и его настроек

Comment: Апач? nginx? или ещё что?

Comment: извините я раньше не сталкивался, не понял что вы имели в виду, вот я нашел Server:nginx/0.7.67

Comment: Каков конфиг nginx? Куда он проксирует?

Comment: В ВП по умолчанию и так отдаёт 404. Если у тебя не отдаёт - ищи кто поломал. Инструкция по поиску виновного в пп 3-6: https://codex.wordpress.org/Как_задавать_правильные_вопросы

Comment: Да, вордпресс по умолчанию имеет переадресацию на страницу 404. Вот пример на моем тест-сайте: http://webyard.site90.com/junk Настроить страницу можно в `Appearance -> editor -> 404.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте шаблон 404.php внутри вашей темы, а о заголовках позаботится сам WordPress